# Blank white space display on select option drop down although it bind data correctly?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, angular7, angular-components

I create dynamic drop down on angular 7 on run time but my problem is when open select option it show

white space on select option although it bind data correctly and  fill correctly but my issue

How to remove blank white space when i make bind to data ?

Here below i create drop down dynamically with name and fill it

```
<div class="form-group" style="display: flex; align-items: center;margin-top:10px;margin-left:20px;">  
         <div *ngFor="let fil of FilterList" style="padding-bottom: 10px;margin-right: 10px;">  
           {{fil.controlName | slice:3:15}}     
           <Select id="{{fil.controlName}}" (change)="onChange($event)" class="form-control"  
             style="width:200px; margin-right:10px;" >  



             <option value="0">-Select-</option>  

             <option *ngFor="let fil2 of this.FilterBinddata" >  
               <div *ngIf="fil.controlName===fil2.filterName ">  
                 {{fil2.reportSource}}  
               </div>  
             </option>  




           </Select>  

           <div>  
           </div>  

         </div>  

       </div>
```

my image problem as below :

[image: blank white space drop down angular 7]

**result of reply thread**
[image: repate data for items]

Answer (score 0):

You are using a condition that isn't sending back true... When the condition sends false, the option is created while the div is NOT. Leading to the option being there and not having any content and hence appearing blank. So the better way to approach it is to create an ng-container before the select and use it for your *ngFor to loop through the filterBinddata. While setting the *ngIf to the option tag itself...

Code example below.

```
<div class="form-group" style="display: flex; align-items: center;margin-top:10px;margin-left:20px;">
  <div style="padding-bottom: 10px;margin-right: 10px;">
    {{fil.controlName | slice:3:15}}
    <div *ngFor="let fil of FilterList">
      <Select id="{{fil.controlName}}" (change)="onChange($event)" class="form-control"
        style="width:200px; margin-right:10px;">
        <option value="0">-Select-</option>
        <ng-container *ngFor="let fil2 of FilterBinddata">
          <option *ngIf="fil.controlName===fil2.filterName">
            {{fil2.reportSource}}
          </option>
        </ng-container>
      </Select>
    </div>
    <div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for reply it is create drop down list with number of items bind

Comment: I see, ok lemme try something else and get back to you

Comment: @ahmedbarbary I fixed it, sorry for answering without trying out my code first... anyway, it was all about changing the position of your *ngIf and *ngFor, setting the *ngIf for the option itself and not it's content... select doesn't allow for tags inside it other than option and the ng-container, hence I used the container for the *ngFor and the *ngIf was on the option